# Client unable to access shared SQL Server (on-Premise) connection

Tags: sql-server, powerapps, data-gateway

I have a shared application in Powerapps using 2 different SQL connections hosted by 2 different On-Premise gateways.  Multiple users are using the App without issue -- everyone has the same share permissions (shared with app, gateways and connections).  For both SQL Server connections, a service account is used to connect.

Only one of the users sees this error when attempting to open the App:
[image: Snippet of error message. User is unable to progress beyond this point.]

The user sees this error for one SQL Server but not the other.  Clicking "Ask for access" sends an email to me with links that take me to the "Share" page for the connections -- but he's already in the list!

I've triple checked all permissions - they are the same as other users who are not experiencing this issue.  I'm not sure what else I have control of to try to fix this issue -- what am I missing?

Comment: What is the environment? Is it on web or device? My guess is that it can be some odd caching issue. If you can send the session ID, I an try to investigate it more.

Comment: This user experiences the same error if he pulls the app up on his phone or on his laptop in a browser (we've tried IE and Chrome).  

I pulled this sessionid from the user while the error was up.

4cab7a37-531e-2fc8-c9b0-8b69b758e95f

Comment: I don't see any error in this session. If this user goes to portal (https://web.powerapps.com/home) under the connections, can he see the SQL connection? Make sure that he is on right environment. Environment menu is on the top right side of the website.

Comment: He's out to lunch. :)  As soon as he gets back, I'll jump in and confirm the environment.

I can say, for sure, that if you navigate to the connections -- it shows that he's connected to the SQL connection.  Also, I had him build a test App using the SQL connection -- this worked just fine.  It only seems to be a problem for the App I published, and only for him.

Comment: For this user and other users, I confirmed that they currently only have the default environment available - our company environment.

Comment: If you're thinking that we should kill it with fire, I've already considered that -- but it's company property, and I don't think they'll agree to it.

Comment: So what I read from your comment is that he can see two SQL connections under his connections that you are the owner of them. Is that correct. I will ask someone in my team to also look at this. Cheers

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct.  Under connections, he can see (and shows to be connected) to 2 SQL Server connections.  When loading the App, he gets the error above for only 1 of them.

Answer (score 0):

With a PowerApp in this particular configuration, you may encounter permission issues if new On-Premise gateways are added after the initial share gesture is performed.

The quickest thing to try is to unshare and reshare the PowerApp with the user who is having access issues. This will force the service to refresh all of the gateway and connection permissions on-demand.

Edit: After re-reading the comment thread with Reza, this may not be a foolproof fix. I think it's still worth trying, however.

Comment: I had already tried unsharing and resharing all shareable things connected to this App including the App itself.  No such luck, I'm afraid. :(